# Printing to a Thermal Receipt Printer using PHP

Tags: php, printing

I have the following code that was supposed to make it able to print something to a thermal receipt printer.

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'print')
{
    $printer = "\\\\localhost\\zebra";

    // Open connection to the thermal printer
    $fp = fopen($printer, "w");
    if (!$fp){
      die('no connection');
    }

    $data = " PRINT THIS ";

    // Cut Paper
    $data .= "\x00\x1Bi\x00";

    if (!fwrite($fp,$data)){
      die('writing failed');
    }

}
```

Although, when I run it nothing happens along with no errors. How does one print from PHP?

Comment: what about using printer_open function .... 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-open.php

Comment: It gives me this: `Call to undefined function printer_open()`

Comment: Umm, just a guess, do you `fclose` at your actual code?

Comment: Dear @user3271851 are you find the solution.Please Help if you have the solution.Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

try this ...

```
<?php 
if ($_GET['action'] == 'print')
{
$printer = "\\\\localhost\\zebra"; 
if($ph = printer_open($printer)) 
{ 
   $data = " PRINT THIS ";  
   // Cut Paper
   $data .= "\x00\x1Bi\x00";
   printer_write($ph, $data); 
   printer_close($ph); 
} 
else die('writing failed');
}
?>
```

Comment: I get this error: `Call to undefined function printer_open()`

Comment: do you enabled the extension in php.ini?

Comment: What would I put in the php.ini file?